# Keeping track of the longest streak in swift

Tags: swift

Apologies if this too simple or has been asked before but I cannot find a solution anywhere.

I have a function that randomly generates 'yes' or 'no'. How would I track and store the longest streak of consecutive 'no's in a sequence?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this and you can store all the streak values in an array and then find the maximum value out of it. Below is the code.

```
var streak = 0
var streakArr = [Int]()

// This will generate the random values

func randomBool() -> Bool {

    return arc4random_uniform(2) == 0
}

for i in 0...10 {

    let obj = randomBool()

    if !obj {

        streak += 1

    } else {

        streak = 0

    }

    streakArr.append(streak)
}

streakArr // OP- [1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
streakArr.max() // will give you the maximum value ie. 3
```

Answer (score 1):

For example let say that `GenerateAnswear()` is your function to generate `Yes` or `No`

```
func GenerateAnswear() -> String {
    switch arc4random() % 2 {
    case 0:
        return "Yes"
    default:
        return "No"
    }
}
```

Lets declare a variable to store streak with initial value `0`
To generate some answears in a row we do a while loop.
In this loop we call for our method `GenerateAnswear()`

```
var n = 10
var streak = 0

repeat {
    let answear = GenerateAnswear()
    streak = answear == "No" ? streak + 1 : 0
    print(answear)
    print("streak \(streak)")
    n = n - 1
} while n > 0
```

To count streak of `No` We are verify the answear in codition if is equal to `No` and assign to is out current `streak` value increase by `1` or `0` if generated answear is different then `No`

```
    streak = answear == "No" ? streak + 1 : 0
```

Here you have an eample output of the code from above. Streak value is stored in our local variable. Do what ever you want to do with it

```
No
streak 1
Yes
streak 0
Yes
streak 0
Yes
streak 0
No
streak 1
No
streak 2
No
streak 3
Yes
streak 0
Yes
streak 0
Yes
streak 0
```